# Using Enum to assign a value

Tags: solidity, contract-development, enum

im new to Solidity.

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this in Solidity using enum.

```
enum Menu {
Burger,
Pizza,
Fries
}

uint price; // storing different prices of different items here

// Assuming that the var userMenu contains the user's selected value from Menu enum 
if (userMenu == Menu.Burger) {
price = 2;
} else if (userMenu == Menu.Pizza){
price = 4;
} else if (userMenu == Menu.Fries) {
price = 1;
}
```

*I know that the initialization of values into price can be done more efficiently. I just want to know if there are any methods to do something like this. Thanks!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try like that:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Test1 {
    Menu userMenu;

    enum Menu {
        Burger,
        Pizza,
        Fries
    }

    uint price; // storing different prices of different items here

    function setUseMenu(Menu _enumIndex) external {
        userMenu = _enumIndex;
    }

    function setPrice() public {
        // Assuming that the var userMenu contains the user's selected value from Menu enum 
        if (userMenu == Menu.Burger) {
            price = 2;
        } else if (userMenu == Menu.Pizza){
            price = 4;
        } else if (userMenu == Menu.Fries) {
            price = 1;
        }
    }

    function getPrice() external view returns(uint) {
        return price;
    }
}
```